# Jquery trigger('focus') bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have two input field `id_bolnica` and `id_odeljenje`, if user insert invalid data for `id_odeljenje`, pop up show and say what is valid data for `id_odeljenje`,  I have problem with new version of Chrome I can't close alert I think because of `.trigger('focus')` , every time when I click ok or click on close it refreshes alert if I remove `.trigger('focus')` it normally close alert, but I need this piece of code because I need from user to stay on that input to enter valid data.
Someone have idea what to do ? in older version of Chrome it works normal.

My code looks like this

```
if(id_bolnica == 119 && !(id_odeljenje == 110 || id_odeljenje == 404 || id_odeljenje == 420)) {
    alert("Dozvoljena odeljenja za izabranu bolnicu su:\n\n"+110+"\n"+404+"\n"+420);

   $('#' + ime_polja_odeljenja).attr("value", "");
   $('#' + ime_polja_odeljenja).css("background-color", "red");
   $('#' + ime_polja_odeljenja).trigger("focus");

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more code?
How do you collect id_bolnica and id_odeljenje variables?

Comment: How do you handle events?

Comment: This depends on the event handler in which this code occurs. Please provide the code where you bind that event handler. If for instance you capture the `blur` event, I suggest to use the `change` or `input` event instead.

Comment: It works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/q3yw8jw8/ maybe your ime_polja_odeljenja is wrong value? check it with alert. If not, try bare javascript: `document.getElementById("myInput").focus();`